# Как в SetInterval передать функцию с параметром

Tags: javascript

Необходимо в вункцию передать параметр, но втаком виде интервал не работает

```
playGame() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.gameService.startLife(this.field), 
    this.timeLeft)
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код можно ещё проще исправить, добавив коллбэк:

```
playGame() {
    this.interval = setInterval(()=>this.gameService.startLife(this.field), 
    this.timeLeft)
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
playGame() {
  this.interval = setInterval(
    this.gameService.startLife, 
    this.timeLeft,
    this.field
  );
}
```

B IE9:

```
playGame() {
  this.interval = setInterval(
    (function () { this.gameService.startLife(this.field); }).bind(this), 
    this.timeLeft
  );
}
```

B IE8:

```
playGame() {
  var that = this;
  this.interval = setInterval(
    function () { that.gameService.startLife(that.field); }, 
    this.timeLeft
  );
}
```

Comment: по моемому в ie параметры не передадутся, когда то сталкивался с таким

Comment: @SergeyArchipov - в IE9 и старше